# Trying to find the minimum number within Scanner user input in Java

Tags: java

I'm coding a test averager in Java. I have to use do while, while, if loops.

I have the user inputting test scores, asking for a negative number to leave the while loop.

I have to display the number of scores entered, the highest, the lowest, and the average.

**However, I am having problems displaying the lowest number as it as popping up as 0.**

For input of 95, 93, 92, 91, and -1:

The number of scores entered: 4
The Highest: 95
The Lowest: 0
The average is: 92

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab7 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("This program computes the average of");
        System.out.println("a list of (nonnegative) exam scores.");
        int sum;
        int numberOfTests;
        int testInput;
        String answer;
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter all the scores to be averaged.");
            System.out.println("Enter a negative number after");
            System.out.println("you have entered all the scores.");
            sum = 0;
            numberOfTests = 0;
            testInput = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (testInput >= 0)
            {
                sum = sum + testInput; 
                numberOfTests++;
                

                 if (testInput < minimum)
                {
                    minimum = testInput;
                }
                
                if (testInput > maximum) 
                {
                    maximum = testInput;
                }
    
                testInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            if (numberOfTests > 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("The number of scores entered: " + numberOfTests);
                System.out.println("The Highest: " + maximum);
                System.out.println("The Lowest: " + minimum);
                System.out.println("The average is: " +
                (sum / numberOfTests));    

            }

            else 
            {
                System.out.println("No scores to average.");
            }

            System.out.println("Want to average another exam?");
            System.out.println("Enter yes or no.");
            answer = keyboard.next();
        }
        
        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    }

    
}
```

Comment: initialize `minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE`. When you initialize minimum to 0, it will always be false in the `if` statement because the `testInput` will be greater than 0.

Comment: There are no *if loops*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialise `minimum` with `0`, so for positive inputs it will always be the smallest value. That means `if (testInput < minimum)` will always be `false`. To fix this, initialise it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead.

In general, it is a good idea to start a *maximum* value with *the lowest possible value*, like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `Double.MIN_VALUE` or in your case with `0`, since there are no negative scores. Furthermore, the *minimum* should be initialised with *the largest possible value*, like described above.

That way, your checks will always work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to this line `int minimum = 0;` as your input scores are greater than **0** thus your this condition will never be satisfied `if (testInput < minimum)` and the value of `minimum` won't never-ever changes and will remain as **0**. Hence define it as `minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Following is your code in a working state and I also made some optimizations which will help you in a better way of writing code:

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int sum = 0, numberOfTests = 0, testInput , minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE , maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       
        System.out.println("This program computes the average of \na list of (nonnegative) exam scores. \n");
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter all the scores to be averaged.");
            System.out.println("Enter a negative number after \nYou have entered all the scores.");
            
            testInput = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (testInput >= 0){
                sum += testInput; 
            
                numberOfTests++;                

                if (testInput < minimum) minimum = testInput;
                
                if (testInput > maximum) maximum = testInput;
                    
                testInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            if (numberOfTests > 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("The number of scores entered: " + numberOfTests);
                System.out.println("The Highest: " + maximum);
                System.out.println("The Lowest: " + minimum);
                System.out.println("The average is: " +
                ((float)sum / numberOfTests));    
            }

            else 
                System.out.println("No scores to average.");
            

            System.out.println("Want to average another exam?");
            System.out.println("Enter yes or no.");

        }
        
        while (keyboard.nextLine().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        
        keyboard.close();
    }
    
}
```

Thanks